# Weird Icons and characters all over my desktop

Tags: icons, language

I am using Windows 10 and I have this really big problem.

All the languages, fonts etc in my PC became weird icons and characters such as squares, dots, circles and more. Another thing, I think it also affects my other software like Photoshop.

Please help me to get rid of this.

Here's a screencap:

[[image: screenshot1]

Comment: What OS do you use? It looks like Windows 8?

Comment: No, it is Windows 10 as I can see many Windows 10 features in Task Bar

Answer (score 0):

If you run Windows 8 / 8.1 [this article](http://www.coderewind.com/2015/01/how-to-fix-corrupt-missing-unreadable-font-on-windows-8/) may help:

[image]

> Step 1: Get a clean copy of windows 8 fonts
>
> There are 2 ways to get a clean default copy of windows 8/8.1 fonts
>
> 1. Copy the contents of a C:\Windows\Fonts directory from a PC that does not have this problem and paste them into the machine
>      C:\Windows\Fonts directory using a USB drive or external hard drive.
>      You can also copy the files directly on the desktop or any temp folder
>      on affected machine.
> 2. Second option is to Download the Windows 8.1 Default Fonts from [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=14BCE195E0EFAD9F!76128&cid=14BCE195E0EFAD9F&group=0&parId=14BCE195E0EFAD9F!103&authkey=!AEO5PWsyfyMteLk&action=locate) and extract it to your desktop..
>
> Step 2: Create a backup of Fonts registry hive
>
> 1. Open the Registry Editor by typing “Regedit” without quotes in the run prompt. You can open the run prompt by using Window Key + R on the
>      keyboard Windows 8.1 run prompt
> 2. Navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts** and click the **File -> Export** option to save a
>      backup.
>
> Step 3: Remove the existing Fonts hive
>
> After taking a backup of the fonts hive, make sure Fonts hive is
>   selected and delete the entire Fonts hive. This is a very critical
>   step for this solution. If you skip this step and do not delete this
>   registry hive and simply copy the font files, after you reboot your
>   machine you might have the same issue. So this step is very critical
>   to fix this issue.
>
> Step 4: Restore the default font files we downloaded in Step 1
>
> 1. Copy the contents of the font files that we got from Step 1 to C:\Windows\Fonts directory of the affected machine. This step will
>      prompt you to confirm if it can continue to install all font, you can
>      safely choose ok and let it continue with the install. This will
>      install all the fonts and register all the fonts in the registry in
>      the same Fonts group we just deleted in Step 3.
> 2. You can also install the font by selecting all the font files and then right on the selected list and choose the first option that shows
>      the UAC icon.
> 3. Reboot the machine after copying the font files even though you might notice that the text is now become readable almost everywhere.
> 4. After reboot verify that you can still see the text in readable format.
>
> Final Thoughts:
>
> One last check after restoring all the font files, open
>   **C:\Windows\Fonts** folder, and your fonts windows should look something
>   like the screenshot below with the list of fonts you just installed.

If you run Windows 7 please take a look at this thread: [Windows 7: Language displays as squares/weird characters](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/291557-language-displays-squares-weird-characters.html)

> Navigate to the control panel, then click on clock, language and
>   region. Now click on region and language and then go to the keyboards
>   and languages tab. Under the installed services tab, click on add. If
>   everything is correct the languages you mean should be listed there
>   (or in the previous tab, if you've already used them). If so, simply
>   click them and hit apply. If they are not listed there, you can find
>   all language packs [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7). The download instructions are on that page,
>   provided by Microsoft.

Comment: OP is using Windows 10, not saying your answer is incorrect though